# how to use ascii character for quote in COPY in cqlsh

Tags: csv, cassandra, sqlbulkcopy, cql3, cqlsh

I am uploading data from a a big .csv file into Cassandra using copy in cqlsh.
I am using cassandra 1.2 and CQL 3.0. 
However since " is part of my data I have to use some other character for uploading my data, I need to use any extended ASCII characters. I tried various approaches but fails.

The following works, but need to use an extended ascii characters for my purpose..

> ```
> copy (<columnnames>) from <filename> where deleimiter='|' and quote = '"';
> copy (<columnnames>) from <filename> where deleimiter='|' and quote = '~';
> ```

When I give  quote='ß', I get the error below:

> :"quotechar" must be an 1-character string

Pls advice on how I can use an extended ASCII character for quote parameter..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, and inspected the source code of cqlsh (it's a python script). In my case, I was generating the csv with python, so it was a matter of finding the right python csv parameters.

Here's the key information from cqlsh:

```
    csv_dialect_defaults = dict(delimiter=',', doublequote=False,
                            escapechar='\\', quotechar='"')
```

So if you are lucky enough to generate your .csv file from python, it's just a matter of using the csv module with:

```
    writer = csv.writer(open("output.csv", 'w'), **csv_dialect_defaults)
```

Hope this helps, even if you are not using python.

Answer (score 0):

A note on the [COPY documentation page](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/cql/COPY) suggests that for bulk loading (like in your case), the [json2sstable](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/sstable2json#sstable2json) utility should be used. You can then load the sstables to your cluster using [sstableloader](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/references/bulkloader#bulkloader). So I suggest that you write a script/program to convert your CSV to JSON and use these tools for your big CSV. JSON will not have any problem handling all characters from ASCII table.